# Fullcalendar Month View - adjust to actual number of weeks in month

Tags: printing, fullcalendar

Using latest fullcalendar.io, the number of weeks that are displayed in month view is appropriate for the first month that renders.  When using the prev/next buttons, if the next/prev month has less weeks than the current month, it still renders the current month's number of weeks.

Right now it's May 2015.  The demo on the site is here: http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/gcal.html

May 2015 renders with 6 weeks, because that's how many are needed.  When I click next to go to June 2015, 6 weeks are still rendered in month view, even though only 5 weeks are needed.

Question: how can the number of weeks that gets rendered adjust to the actual number of weeks that a given month has?  This means that May 2015 would have 6 weeks, but the table would reduce to 5 weeks for June 2015.

This is important when trying to print a monthly calendar.  It's May right now, but someone might want to click next and print June, which is coming up.  The June calendar should only have 5 weeks, but I can only make it display with 6, since I entered June from May.

Thanks for only tips on this.
ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your looking for the [`fixedWeekCount`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/) option. From the documentation, you can see that:

> If `true`, the calendar will always be 6 weeks tall. If `false`, the calendar will have either 4, 5, or 6 weeks, depending on the month.

So, if you want to display the correct number of weeks per selected month, you should set that option to false when fullCalendar is initialized:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    fixedWeekCount: false
});
```

Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ygz2vtLg/) for a working demo.

Answer (score 3):

For those poor souls who are still stuck with older version of fullcalendar (v1.6.4) use:

`weekMode: "variable"`

Comment: @Druzion, apologies, I am new here... So, should I add my alternate approach in accepted answer then?

Comment: No you should not. I understand you are new, but it is pointless answering a question that already has an accepted answer. If you answered this within a week of the other answer getting accepted, you could post you alternate solution, but now it is pointless. The only reason you should should not is because when people come looking for answers they don't want to scroll through lots, they just want one that will solve their problem, and the first answer did that.